# Class cast exception when deploying EAR using Spring in Glassfish

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, classcastexception, redeploy

When redeploying an EAR (with no code changes made) to a Glassfish server (v3) without restarting Glassfish first, I get a ClassCastException when trying to instantiate a bean from the Spring container.

I understand that a class definition is a combination of the class and the loader and when the class has static members it may not get removed from PermGen causing this exception on redeployment, but my class has no static members.

Any ideas on what else might cause this and how to stop this happening?

Thanks

Comment: I assume it works fine if you do restart?